# PHP get unknown $var from url

Tags: php

I've a page that pass dynamically different `$var` in URL on another page.
My goal is to retrieve and list this var on the second page in order to pass them to another page.

On page A the user can choose a value via select X, Y, Z (just one, both or as the user likes) the select is passed via form GET.

**EXAMPLE**

- user choice is: X,Z
- page B receives  http://example.com?X=X&Z=Z

my issue is that I don't know the var name so I cant do `$_GET['X']`, `$_GET['Z']`

Please can someone can help?

Many THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

You can illiterate over whole _GET var like

```
foreach ($_GET as $name => $value)
```

And build your request URL

Answer (score 1):

1. Loop through the `$_GET` array:

   ```
   foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
       echo "$key: $value";
   }
   ```
2. Use sensible, known key names:

   ```
   example.com?choices[]=X&choices[]=Z

   var_dump($_GET['choices']);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $_GET super global array also.

```
$arguments = array();

foreach( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
    $arguments[$key] = $value
}

print_r( $arguments );
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` helps you to detect the query string after the `?` in the URL.